# How can I do for moving questions into this site?

Tags: support

I found that some of the questions e.g. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13008 maybe more suitable for placing in this site. How can I do for moving questions into this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no way to move *old* questions from other Stack Exchange sites to this site. However, there is nothing wrong with asking a question closely related to one that exists on another site here. If you do so, I would suggest to mention the other question and to make an effort to make it somewhat different and even more suitable for this site.

It is in principle possible to move/migrate recent questions from one SE site to another. For some pairs of sites this can be achieved by users via voting. However, since this site is still in beta this is not possible. Moderators could still migrate question here but this should be done sparingly and I doubt a questions like the one you mention, even though it is not strictly too old I think, would be considered for migration.

Comment: I saw some successful examples of coercively moving the questions to another site, the questions will have a dialogue block telling that migrate from which site, and the users in the questions will have chances to have no user pages. How these can do?

Comment: Yes, as I said it is in principle  possible. It is called migration. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work for details. But as you can see there answered question should rather not be migrated, excluding the question you mentioned. And as you can see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169983/are-there-precedents-to-migrate-a-post-to-a-beta-site  it is possible but rather discouraged to migrate to public beta sites (to private beta sites, which we are at the moment it is likely impossible).